# How to not consider duplicate value in a Table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, set

I'm implementing a JTable, where an user can define the TimeTable. 
Every subject has a number of credits, and I have to count the sum of all credits in a week. Obviously, for do that it's necessary to count one time all duplicate subject(I would not count two time the credits of the same subject).

For example, if the JTable is
[image: Imagine of an example TimeTable]

I would like to get the value `Math`,`English`,`Science`, `Philosophy`, `Art` only **ONE** time. I've tried to do this with the follower method:

```
private void getOnce (String[] dailyLessons)
{   
    Set<String> weekSubjects = new HashSet<String>();
    int weeklyCredits=0;

        //dailylessons is a String[] that contains the lessons of the day
    Collections.addAll(weekSubjects, dailyLessons);

    //String[] week would contain every subject only one time
        String [] week = weekSubjects.toArray(new String[0]);

    //for all the subject I get its credits
    for (int i=0; i<week.length; i++)
     {
        if (!week[i].equals("no"))
        {
            String [] credits= week[i].getCredits;
            weeklyCredits += credits;
        }
        }
}
```

But it does not work. Could you explain me why? A correct version of my code will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> But it does not work. Could you explain me why?

- read Oracle tutorial [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- all data for `JTables view` are stores in ([Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)) XxxTableModel
- if isn't there any definition for `XxxTableModel` then `DefaultTableModel` is used

> A correct version of my code will be very appreciated.

- good one

Comment: I've yet defined a Model for my Table. And I get the dailyLessons value from its method `getValueAt(row,col)`. In this way I have six dailyLessons String[] with Subject Values. But I want to do a summary and consider every subject once time only. Can you help me? 

p.s. : i've read for several days oracle pages. If i write here is to have a concreter help. Could you provide it to me?

Comment: JTable and its model to display only value which is added, sure for better help soone post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for XxxTableModel from local variable

Comment: In my opinion the Jtable is not necessary, in reason which I've yet provided the table (the model of the table is standard) e the way in which it is defined. I simply desire to implement a method that erase duplicate values in a JTable argument. And Jtable is yet provided.